Can I measure the vibration of low-reflective material using a Michelson interferometer?
I recently built a Michelson interferometer and was thrilled to observe my first fringes. I became even more excited when I successfully measured extremely low sound vibrations by physically attaching a speaker to one of the metal-plated mirrors.
My setup includes:

A green laser diode
A beamsplitter
Two metal-plated mirrors
A photodiode for recording the interference pattern

The setup looks like this:

I’m now considering modifying the setup to directly measure the speaker membrane by removing Mirror 1 and allowing the laser to reflect off the speaker membrane. However, this introduces some complications:

The reflectivity of the speaker membrane is ~10%.
The membrane scatters light in all directions.
I cannot enhance the membrane's reflective properties (it needs to stay as it is).
Given these limitations, what steps could I take to improve the signal and still observe interference fringes?

One idea I’ve considered is using optics (e.g., a lens) in front of the speaker to better collect and direct the scattered light. Additionally, I thought about using a neutral-density (ND) filter to balance the intensity between the two arms of the interferometer.
Are there other reasonable approaches I could explore to optimize the setup and improve the measurement signal?

You can use sort of Optical amplifier on the scattered signal from a speaker membrane.

Your ND filter and imaging are good ideas: you enhance collection efficiency from sample arm and keep interference contrast by reducing the reference arm's intensity. You will need to make the same imaging on both arms: place a lens at f distance from speaker and another copy of the lens at f distance from reference mirror. Choose an arrangement where the amplitude of the membrane movement is within the confocal distance. I disagree with Agnius, as the complexity of the system will be much higher with no need.
